# Locking files (in python)

Tags: python, file, locking

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Does read, write in python using file.read(), file.write() happen using locks ?
   Or can read, write happen at the same time ?
2. I have pickled object to a file on the disk. Now multiple threads can read the pickled model. But I also want to update the pickled file. Now one way is to lock the file on every read, write. But this would be inefficient since locking the files only when they are being read by different process is unneccary.

How should I solve this ?

Comment: If you want to use locks, use shared locks for read and exclusive locks for write. I don't know a cross-platform way, but in Linux at least, `fcntl.flock` gives an interface to the advisory file locking functionality in the kernel.

Comment: Python uses whatever is available on the current OS.  So this is very likely to differ from OS to OS.  If you want locking, you need to do it yourself.  Regarding your second question, this is precisely the purpose of a read-write lock.  You haven't yet said whether your processes are all started from a single Python thread, or if they are just multiple processes all interested in this file, so that may affect which r-w lock you use.    https://renatocunha.com/2015/11/ctypes-mmap-rwlock/

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks for the comment. I was able to track down the rwLock using the shared locks concept mentioned by alani. So all my processes are basically web server threads so essentially they are spawned from a single parent thread.